# Inferring type results of function's 1st arg into types of second arg

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have been trying to bend Typescript's inference engine to the max for a util that I am developing, however, I am struggling to get it to work as I would like.

The generic util receives a set of "mapper" functions as the 1st argument, and a "transformer" function as the 2nd argument.

The results of the "mapper" functions, will become the inputs to the "transformer" function.

I'd like to dynamically infer the argument types to the "transformer" function based on the data that is resolved by the "mappers".

I have created the following basic illustration of this:

```js
type Transformation<
  Data extends object = {},
  Result = any,
  Mappers extends Array<(data: Data) => any> = Array<(data: Data) => any>
> = (
  mappers: Mappers,
  transform: (
    // Over here I am trying to infer out the results of my mapper, with this
    // implementation supporting up to 2 mappers
    ...args: Mappers extends [(data: Data) => infer Arg1]
      ? [Arg1]
      : Mappers extends [(data: Data) => infer Arg1, (data: Data) => infer Arg2]
      ? [Arg1, Arg2]
      : any[]
  ) => Result,
) => void;

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const personTransformer = {} as Transformation<Person, string>;

personTransformer(
  // mappers:
  [person => person.name, person => person.age],
  //                 |                      |
  // |---------------|                      |
  // |                                      |
  // |    |---------------------------------- 
  // |    |
  (name, age) => `${name} is ${age} years old`,
);
```

[Click here for the TypeScript playground of this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmB7OBbBwCWGSAPAFBRQAieCUEAHsBEgCYpQYBGAVhAMbAoAXigBvAL4AaclABKEFAFcANoJHIQ0igFkEYSHHYMmrdgEE4iEMQAULGgC4qNAJTCAfFA2eRFq7ftgBCdqILchT29SHygbGVx9CEMnXUTDLShgRFRMHCc4igoAeiKoAHkANySoAAsk6ABJL2xMuBB8JABzTIwoDrRqjEVBYDqoOAUVYHYMNChsEHm9A0koAHd8Ucya-BQZYtL8bDBlCGxmIIIiKCV9LAIuqEUwHqgAJiW0vcKoADp-hBwTooFLLJJGRjMNhQADadkczjCHj6SAGcCgFk6AEYALr7QoAflhmNx+IooK+dEhplh8KCIVcyP61RJqzpwURCHCnmZ6MxbzxPwoRJhrIxQIFZKgTg0MMFUG5ckmqmkioqGHwLAA3KRSB0mHA0Ag+NAAArg66iGRIBDnJwoLIdTo6igIToQJxIRTYThJHXiXV8IgOqAGFBEeDIdBYc7okQSLzsSM5GN4Qgkc2GIirB1wJ3uHWkMMR7LRnBJApQEqfMMOGQw4tIZGN34286rRvNi1IX5uiA4jLVoXDoUAHxHE5Ho5k1dHAFoF4ul8vx5O1xRpwcoKv17u95uq6Ud9vl6ez+fz1AZ0efgebG2IKs+4qAAYAElED-EfXYH7735ACBARmZQWBfVUtSAA)

I would like the transformer function to dynamically be inferred as `(string, number) => string`, however, it is being typed as `(any, any) => string`.

Is there any way I can get TypeScript to do this type of inference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fundamental issue here was that you were hoping by using a [generic parameter default](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults) for `Mappers` (which I'll call `M`), you would somehow get it to be inferred.  Unfortunately it will just use the default instead of trying to infer anywhere.  So you are specifying `Data` (that's `D` for me) and `Result` (that's `R`) and getting the default `M` which uses `any` all over the place.

The fix is essentially to make `Transformation<D, R>` itself a generic function which depends on type `M`.  So instead of `type Transformation<D, R, M> = ()=>{}`, you have `type Transformation<D, R> = <M>()=>{}`.  That will let `M` be inferred from its use.  (For all I know you should just make it `type Transformation = <D, R, M>()=>{}` and let all three generic parameters be specified by the caller of a `Transformation`, but that has to do with your use case.)

Here's how I'd go about defining it:

```
// less restrictive form of ReturnType<T>
type Ret<T> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never;

type Transformation<D, R> = <M extends ReadonlyArray<(data: D) => any>>(
  mappers: M | [], // | [] hints that mappers should be a tuple type
  transform: (...args: { [K in keyof M]: Ret<M[K]> }) => R
) => (data: D) => R; // I assume you want to actually transform things
```

You could replace the `(data: D) => R` with `void` if you want it to work like your version; I just thought it made sense that a `Transformation<D, R>` should produce something that actually transforms a `D` into an `R`.

The `M | []` is used instead of `M` because it serves as a [hint](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179) to interpret the `mappers` parameter as a tuple type instead of as an array... and you need that, so that `transform`'s parameters are strongly typed in order (and not just a big union of things).

And note that the `transform` function operates on a [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) corresponding to the *return types* of the functions in `mappers`.

We might as well make an implementation instead of using `{}` at runtime:

```
const transformer = <D, R>() =>
  (((mappers: ((d: D) => any)[], transform: (...a: any[]) => R) => (data: D) =>
    transform(...mappers.map(m => m(data)))) as any) as Transformation<D, R>;
```

That has to use a few type assertions, but it basically applies each function in `mappers` to `data` and the resulting array is spread into the `transform()`.

Finally we can use the above to get a `Transformation<Person, string>`:

```
const personTransformer = transformer<Person, string>();
```

And we see it behave as you'd like:

```
const p = personTransformer(
  [person => person.name, person => person.age],
  (name, age) => name.toUpperCase() + " IS " + age.toFixed(1) + " YEARS OLD"
);
```

Where `name` and `age` are known to be of type `string` and `number`, respectively.

And the implementation I gave above yields this:

```
console.log(p({ name: "Billy", age: 9 }));
// BILLY IS 9.0 YEARS OLD
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBsFMGdtAnGAXeBLAxk1A3SoBmA9vALaiH6gBKkSArvAHYAqAngA6QA8zAfAFBIOeGkh69QAXlDNQkAB5JIjACZwAFADptAQ3gBzaAC5QOxqwCUUiakb5I8aqAD8Tk40i54Abn6DhMvBm0ESkOliEjFwAIgA01BLSXACycorKatSQOiqR4KwAgvBBrFzqKuE6JtFWkhJmrLy86vygoCQ67JzwxqCpAD6gANoAuvEgoIOjoAAWtkhwSDPh7Z3dcNAzhHTgKqAARng6oPTsUCfCrSdBjCHEJCZauga9AN7DANKgtqAA1pCsCh9EYmUQpIYfEYSAC+tQkVH4cNA5Uq1SRVG8oAmAElTLA6CQ8IC6KAAO5mJAnQimTB0HTgfLXYKhMhLWyGPzzBz4HToPAABQc0EioFeV0YOkJJmgKHZvjaOn0kHcBMOPn40L8E2SqH0M0pOjgpMgDNW-1MjG+JDOkEJjCQ4VQIqBbOg-HQkRlTNuLIcUlAMXiVGacKu6nDHS6Qse5TR1gtllG8RQzPuj20miqCdG6KRKIdcbqVzaKZ99yemkj60rnXUZDq7XzOgsLashoTbbgzBudzCESicQSvn4E0YhFJZLwSspxMc3dTfadUUFPUi8RlaEY+l4vg9t0p60i87LpD90lLvcJ8C4K+FjHXsq3IeHe697H9h5YPd98BabSGn7xp+mgSoS8SAQ2wGKpAYxhqBkDxNBSLwZoSCEAAqlG8AAMKGpA6hWAA1KAABEoDYgAyqRoDEdBqGEAAYqg8iQCo6gAIxEdRACaACiBRUFRADyAAy0QkYivgTEsRz7IQuDfBsKCRPojJCJwKh+K+hBQJo4CEPo6jsOo7zwSYJEAEKoAyrAkYhSomAAnKAsIWFJYAWdiIkidx5FUY5mgAAygHxAnCWJ-BAA)